# Почему тип string не поддерживается в библиотеке C++?

Tags: c++, библиотеки

Всем привет. Написал библиотеку в С++. В файле заголовка при написаний функций в качестве параметра хочу передать переменную типа string. Но почему IDE ругает. Вот ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки:
C++ спецификация связывания несовместима с предыдущей (объявлено в строке 107 из)

А в .срр файле все нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете написано что это ошибка IntelliSense или что то типа этого. Не особо понял. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: почитайте https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/definitions-and-declarations-cpp?view=msvc-160 нужно дописать dllexport

Comment: В .срр файл добавил `extern DllExport void StartEncryption(string path);` А в .h файл изменил на `extern HOMOMORPHICFORTEXT_API void StartEncryption(std::string path);` Пишет что: 
**Ошибка C2065 string: необъявленный идентификатор** и 
**Ошибка C2146 синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед идентификатором "path"**

Answer (score 1):

Вы же написали `extern C` -  а это значит, что функция должна соответствовать си спецификации (компилятор с++ сгенерирует имя функции так, что бы ее мог позвать код на си). А в Си нет классов, не говоря уже о string. Используйте `const char*` или не используйте extern C.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали. Теперь ругает на void. Пишет требуется идентификатор.

Comment: Не то чтобы это совсем не правильная рекомендация, но к ошибке она не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: `extern "C"` - всего-лишь имя функции не шифрует, так что в плюсах это можно. Проблема в другом.

Comment: @AlexGlebe так в чем же?

Comment: Может быть вы реализацию написали в каком-то другом пространстве имён. Полный текст то вы не показали. Посмотрите внимательно, чтобы было без пространств. И на всякий случай в `.cpp` добавьте ещё раз `extern "C"` А может надо ещё раз дописать `dllexport`

Comment: Если ругается на void, то надо показать как именно ругается.

Comment: @KoVadim я же сказал выше. Пишет что требуется идентификатор.

Comment: а Вы понимаете разницу между `string`, `std::string` и `const char*` ?